# What thread scenario the method will run ?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I created a service running a sepeated process . In the exported method (AIDL) , I have some code regarding UI , like changing icon in Floating windows,

Currently I ran into an issue , the UI operation in the method always doesn't work. As a result of fact , I tried to log the thread id to check the issue. and the method exactly runs a non-main UI thread.

On the other hand , I invoke asynchTask class in the same scenario, and it does always works . The fact seems to voliate the rule that the aynchTask must be involed in main thred . 
Would you please help to enlighten me by sharing more details or figuring out the "tricky" thing here .

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: seems from the code `onPreExecute` will be called from the thread you started the `AsyncTask`, but `onPostExecute` will be forced to be called from `Handler` cycle which runs on `UIThread`, which method did you implement?

Comment: Thanks to MoshErsan. The SDK documents indicatest explicitly that "The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
The task instance must be created on the UI thread."

Answer (score 0):

Also, I really wanna know more details on what scenario AIDL method runs